# Android using two countdowntimers

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

In my app, i'm using two different `CountDownTimers` that have same values. I have two buttons to control them but when i press the button twice, it starting from the beginning. I want to keep its last value.

**Here is my code:**

```
t1 = new CountDownTimer(white, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        btnWhite.setText("seconds remaining: " + l / 1000);
        white = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
};

t2 = new CountDownTimer(black, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        btnBlack.setText("seconds remaining: " + l / 1000);
        black = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
};

btnBlack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        t1.start();
        t2.cancel();
    }
});

btnWhite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        t2.start();
        t1.cancel();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two timers?

Comment: Are you pressing one button twice, or are you pressing both the buttons once or are you pressing both the buttons twice?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Timers are same but their working times may be different. I'm trying to develop chess clock.

Comment: I'm pressing button Black, then White and then Black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and it works!

I have two `TextView`s and two `Button`s. The black button is next to the black text view and the white button is next to the white text view.

First I declare the important constants.

```java
//contains the elapsed time for each of the timers
long blackElapsed=0,whiteElapsed=0;

//contains the total time with which we start new timers
long totalWhite = 30000;
long totalBlack = 30000;
```

Next I initialise the `CountDownTimers`. Whatever you put in here doesn't matter. I only have this so that the timers will be initialised with some value. 
The reason is that they have to be initialised in order to be able to `.cancel()` them later in the `OnClickListener`s.

```java
black = new CountDownTimer(totalWhite, 1000){
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }
};
white = new CountDownTimer(totalBlack, 1000){
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }
};
```

Finally the `OnClickListener`s for the buttons. (`W` is white textView and `B` is black textView and `b` is black button and `w` is white button)

```java
w.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        black.cancel();
        //using the elapsed time to start a new timer
        totalBlack = totalBlack - blackElapsed;
        //this preserves milliseconds by ticking every millisecond
        white = new CountDownTimer(totalBlack, 1){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                B.setText(l+"");
                blackElapsed=totalBlack-l;  //updating the elapsed time
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
//we do a similar thing with the other player's button
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        white.cancel();
        totalWhite = totalWhite - whiteElapsed;
        black = new CountDownTimer(totalWhite, 1){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                W.setText(l+"");
                whiteElapsed=totalWhite-l;
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but buttons are not working. I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: @CagriYalcin What works now? And what do you mean by the buttons are not working?

Comment: Sorry the total time was 0 i changed it now it works but same problem.

Comment: I mean timers are resetting while using buttons.

Comment: @CagriYalcin Try swapping `++blackTimeElapsed;` and `++whiteTimeElapsed;`

Comment: @CagriYalcin Actually don't listen to my previous suggestion yet, I made a mistake in my code. Try it again now

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: @CagriYalcin Give me some time, I'm creating a new project to test this

Comment: @CagriYalcin IT WORKS NOW!

Comment: Perfect !! It worked thank you so much my friend :))

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code.

It is obvious because your timers initialised with default values. when you start again it won't take new values of white/black.

To achieve what you want you have to initialise timer with new values before starting it.

I have done some correction in your code. you can check that out.

**Make Two methods**

```
public void timerStart1(long timeLengthMilli) {
    t1 = new CountDownTimer(timeLengthMilli, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            isRunning1 = true;
            tv1.setText("seconds remaining: " + l / 1000);
            white = l;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isRunning1 = false;
        }
    }.start();
}

public void timerStart2(long timeLengthMilli) {
    t2 = new CountDownTimer(timeLengthMilli, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            isRunning2 = true;
            tv2.setText("seconds remaining: " + l / 1000);
            black = l;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isRunning2 = false;
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**and set setOnClickListener like this**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!isRunning1) {
            isRunning2 = false;
            timerStart1(white);
            if (t2 != null)
                t2.cancel();
        }
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!isRunning2) {
            isRunning1 = false;
            timerStart2(black);
            if (t1 != null)
                t1.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE :**

Please check updated code and take these extra variables

```
boolean isRunning1 = false, isRunning2 = false;
```

Hope this will help you.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Many thanks, that was helpful but a new problem is i think this code is not keeping milliseconds. When i was repeatedly press those buttons for 5 seconds(for example), timers are not changing.

Comment: it is working fine in my case.. i have checked until both timers don't get to end. can you be more specific about your problem? cuz may be i misunderstood you.

Comment: Sorry for late, my problem is about milliseconds. For example i'm starting both timers for once.I see 600, 599,598 etc.. Then i press and wait almost 1 second(still 598 seconds, it didn't change yet) and i stop it. But when i start it again it must be changed. I mean the timers are not keeping milliseconds i think. When i start it, it counts 1000 milliseconds and again and again. Sorry for bad english.